# Where does chartjs document what is required in the myChartConfig to instantiate using myChart = new Chart(ctx, myChartConfig)

Tags: chart.js

I have deduced by trial and error that the `myChartConfig` in `var myChart = new Chart(ctx, myChartConfig);` must contain a valid `type` key.

Even if I try to specify a global default thus: `Chart.defaults.global.type = 'line';`, unless I include

```
myChartConfig = {
  type: 'bar'
}
```

I get an error '"undefined" is not a chart type.'

This appears to be the only required key in the `myChartConfig` object. I looked in the documentation but could not find where the constructor is documented beyond https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/charts.html and this does not specify what is required for the chart config.

Answer (score 1):

`type` is not an attribute of `options` but it belongs to the higher level `configuration` object.

All attributes inside `options` are optional. I didn't find this information in chart.js documentation but in the TypeScript type definitions repository that contains the specification of the `interface ChartOptions` in the file [`types/chart.js/index.d.ts`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/chart.js/index.d.ts).

Below code snippet from https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/ illustrates that it's fine to provide an empty `options` object or no `options` at all.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'My First dataset',
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
            borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
            data: [0, 10, 5, 2, 20, 30, 45]
        }]
    },
    options: {} // may be omitted
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="80"> </canvas>
```

Comment: I will edit the question to make it clear that my options object is of type Chart.ChartConfiguration

Comment: Thanks uminder. I used the word 'options' to describe the second parameter to the Chart constructor. The TypeScript type definition you kindly link to does this also (2nd parameter is "options: Chart.ChartConfiguration"). This object has an optional 'options' key, but still has a 'type' key (```type: 'line'``` in your code snippet above). The TypeScript definition is useful - thanks! - but it tags the type as optional, but if it is ommitted the chart throws an uncaught error, so it is not really optional - unless there is a way to set the default using Charts.defaults.global. that I missed.